# Upper tail bound on product of 2 independent chi^2 or Gamma variables

Tags: probability, distribution-tails

We have two independent Gaussian vectors: $X \sim N(0,I_k)$, $Y \sim N(0,I_r)$ independent of $X$.
I'm looking for a tail bound on the product of their square norms.

$Pr_{X,Y}[\|X\|^2\cdot \|Y\|^2 > t]\le ?$

when $t$ is larger than some threshold.

Even a ploynomially decaying bound would be sufficient.

Comment: I think that you may use Cauchy schwartz to say that $P(||X||^2||Y||^2 > t) \leq P(||XY||^2 > t) \leq P(X\cdot Y > \sqrt{t}) $

Comment: No, I guess your inequality is the wrong way around.